# search for 2 parameters in column and returning a third column

Tags: excel, search

I am trying to search from inside spreadsheet 1 into spreadsheet 2 for 2 things that must be true and if so, pull back another column row. 
  I want to search column A for the number 12345 and column B for the string "GBP" but I do not know what row 12345 and "GBP" will occur on. If found (there can only ever be 1 result returned so don't worry about multiple results) I need to return the value in column C.

The thing is - I am finding this tricky. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Create a column C where each cell to the right of data contains the formula

```
=IF(AND(A2=12345,B2="GBP"),1,0)
```

When you have copied that formula into each cell down the entire column, search that column for a "1".  The "1" is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is 1 row matching the criteria, you can use [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) to get the value from the matching cell:

- assuming `A2=12345` and `B2="GBP"` on the current sheet,
- sum all values on Sheet 1 column C where both columns A and B match the specified criteria:

  ```
  =SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,
  Sheet1!A:A, A2,
  Sheet1!B:B, B2)
  ```

Comment: Hi Aprillion no, you mis-sunderstand. I need both criteria to be true to return the value in column C. Also - I do not know what row 12345 and GBP will be on...

Comment: I did not mis-understand, please start by going through some Excel tutorials to learn the basic concepts - `A2` and `B2` are just examples, obviously if the criteria are on a different row, just edit the formula. and if you need to find the values for multiple records, just copy&paste in the formula to multiple rows, the row numbers will update automatically